# Linux Mint does not ask for WiFi username and password ("eduroam" at university)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi

I just installed Linux Mint and I am totally new in the Linux world. At my home I have WiFi and I successfully connected with my home WiFi. Connect with my home WiFi I only need password. No username is required.

But at my university, my internet name is `eduroam`. Whenever I try to connect as `eduroam` nothing happens. No pop up where I can insert my username and password.

I checked with other WiFi. I see there are two types of WiFi I think,

- one which only require password and
- the second type which requires both username and password.

My laptop only connect to the first type of WiFi which requires only password but it doesn't connect with second type of WiFi where both username and password is required. Even it doesn't ask for username and password as also.

How can I connect my Linux Mint 17 with `eduroam` WiFi?

Comment: Try to add the WiFi network as `WPA2 Enterprise` type, where you can enter an Identity

Comment: As I told in my post, from where can I access WPA Enterprise? I do not see such option

Comment: Open nm-connection-editor in terminal and then click on edit option and then do what Lambert asked.

Comment: Your university is probably providing information about how to connect to the Eduroam network somewhere on its web pages. If not, contact a local IT helpdesk and they will help you get things set up.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem at my university, it's caused by Linux Mint not having default settings for WPA2 Enterprise connections. You can fix it by doing the following:

1. Open 'Network Settings'
2. Choose 'Connect to a Hidden Network'
3. For Network Name, put the name of the network ('eduroam' in your case)
4. For Network Security, choose 'WPA & WPA2 Enterprise'
5. For Authentication, choose 'Protected EAP (PEAP)'
6. Select "No CA certificate is required"
7. Add your username and password and click connect

I was able to find this solution from the user [mcganical on this forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=188155)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your university uses the kind of wifi that you see in bars and trains. You need to connect to the wifi network, which doesn't require any password. Then you open your browser and browse to any webpage, but get redirected to the university wifi website. There you have to enter username and password.

In Linux Mint, click the wifi icon and see if you can locate the university wifi, then connect to that. So first you have to connect to the eduroam network, or whatever it is called. Then you open your browser, login, and after that everything (that is allowed) works. So if you use a mail client like Apple Mail or Thunderbird, that should work to.

Comment: It is not same as trains. We don't have to do all those stuff from browser. In my mobile I did the same, had to insert password and username but not from browser

Comment: Why don't you ask at your university? They should have a helpdesk. Even if they don't officially support Linux, there probably is an admin that knows how this works.

Answer (score 0):

The exact settings for Eduroam WiFi vary in some way between different universities.  Therefore Eduroam provide a different installer for each known university.  If your university settings are known to Eduroam, you can download an installer, *including for Linux*.

(I don't know whether this was possible when the question was originally asked).

https://cat.eduroam.org/

I looked at the Linux download description for one university.  I suspect the descriptions are mostly the same for each university.

> The installer is in the form of a Python script. It will try to configure eduroam® under NetworkManager and if this is either not appropriate for your system or your version of NetworkManager is too old, a wpa_supplicant config file will be created instead.
>
> The installer will create .cat_installer sub-directory in your home directory and will copy your server certificates there. In order to connect to the network you will need an account from your organisation. You should consult the support page to find out how this account can be obtained. It is very likely that your account is already activated.
>
> You will be requested to enter your account credentials during the installation. This information will be saved so that you will reconnect to the network automatically each time you are in the range.

Google also currently finds an old screenshot of `nm-connection-editor` [here](https://installer.eduroam.hr/eng_faq.php) (click on the FAQ that mentions "Network Manager").

If you want to use `nm-connection-editor` specifically, you *might* need to make sure you install it first.  I.e. do this at home, where you have a working network connection to download it :-).  (Just try to run the command from a terminal.  If it is not installed already, then it should tell you how to do so).

The screenshot shows you one example configuration.  The example is for the university where your username ends in `@skole.hr`.  The "Anonymous Identity" field is therefore `anonymous@skole.hr`.  Adjust the "Anonymous Identity" you use accordingly.

```
Security: WPA2 & WPA2 Enterprise
Authentication: Tunnelled TLS
Anonymous Identity: anonymous@skole.hr
CA Certificate: eduroam_skole.hr_CA.pem [change file]
Inner authentication: PAP
Username: insert-your-username-here@skole.hr
Password: insert-your-password-here
```

In newer versions of Linux, there is also seems to be a Domain field.  It appears to allow it to be left blank.

However, we need to get this mysterious certificate file from somewhere, so that we can have a *secure* connection (not leaking your username and password).

To obtain a certificate, look at the IT help page on your university website.

Alternatively, extract the certificate from the EduRoam installer.  For example, when you open the current Linux Python installer in a text editor, you can just find the CA certificate and copy+paste it into a new file.  Save the new file with a filename like that shown in the screenshot.  In other words, save it to a filename which ends in `.pem`.

The content for the CA certificate file is exactly the text which starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, and which ends with the last instance of `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.  There may be several parts, and hence several BEGIN and END markers, but you should see all the parts are together. Each installer download only provides one specific CA certificate file, for one specific university.  Do not include anything else in the file - in particular do not copy any quotation marks immediately before `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.