# Non root user unable to conect wifi network on the standard way [LINUX MINT]

Tags: networking, wifi, gnome-keyring, non-root-user

I am a enthusiastic linux user and I offered my experience to perform system upgrade on 40 old Classmate PCs (SEE system information on image bellow ) which were runing a deprecated ubuntu version. So, with the proper authorizations, I performed the upgrade and in near future I hope that students can use them for their porpouses (like navigation, researchs, to access Google Classroom functionalities and to make projects and communication with Arduinos. Those last two were not possible before).

[image]

When I started I knew I would have some challenges regarding permissions because, for the students, I would create a account with some restrictions (security porpouses). But I did not expect difficulties with simple tasks, like to connect wifi netwoks at the school or nearby, for the students.

During instalation of the new Linux Mint XFCE 19.3 32bits (image loaded via USB) and even after restart (when I log in the standard non privileged user created - sudoer) everething seems to works fine and I am able to connect the networks I desire (and I seem to have good and stable conections).
The problem arises when I login the new account created. This accont is not able to connect any network listed (the password is not even asked, the system only shows "you are disconected" and you can't do much). Let me be more clear: **When I try to connect any network with this new user (aluno/student - not admin) it simply does not ask the wifi pass key, and show that you are disconected. Not even networks already set for the admin acc (escola) work here. I only get internet for this specific aluno user if I use cable (ethernet) or if I make the trick of setting network via hidden option (that is say I enter the option for setting hidden network, I type the SSID [which is actually not hidden, SIC], choose the WPA2 security and Type the Key)**
This is the most interesting aspect: why is it when I take one of those networks and pretend it is hidden and enter its exact name, choose the security and add manualy the password, the system connects. I know this is a stupid workaround that allow to connect without need further permissions, but other users won't know about it by default.

On attempts to solve, I already gave all privileges that I know of on user configuration, and I even added the user to the netdev group (via `$ sudo usermod -aG netdev alunocj33`). Nothing solves. **I would apreciate some help with this issue.**

**What is happening and how to solve this problem??**

[image]

*Addendum*: I did many search for solutions for this problem in the internet and found only few similar. First I thought the problem was on the card or on the drive installed since I found some other users reporting such unstabilities with RTL8188EE (but the alternative drives suggested to solve the issues wasn't availabre anymore - e.g. lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git on GitHub).
I am trying to solve this since 2019 when I format the first units to use during my robotic classes. Then I relized the problem and should have ask for help. I am doing it now because that many machines with such strange behavior is a mistake. Please, if you have a clue on the solution, let me know.
Sorry for my explanation, I have some difficulties since I am not native in english.

_______________ **Further tests** _______________

**Unsecured wifi Network** > the same bahavior of secured ones: It does not connect!!

**Tethering USB** > Connection is easily stablished (on the same way of ethernet cable).

**journalctl run (below):**

1st > attempt to connect normaly > FAIL

2nd > connecting same network via hidden option > SUCCESS

OBS: Could not use sudo because user aluno**** has no such permission. Even with sudo permission, the retun journalctl are the same for this user ( **device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed'** - tested on several machines).

```
alunocj25@escolacj25-EC10IS2:~$ journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Fri 2021-01-29 13:11:30 -03. --
mar 15 16:40:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <warn>  [1615837204.0992] device (wlp2s0): No agents were available for this request.
mar 15 16:40:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837204.0994] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:40:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837204.1037] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
mar 15 16:40:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <warn>  [1615837204.1059] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1'
mar 15 16:40:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837204.1100] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:40:24 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:40:27 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:40:30 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:40:32 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:40:32 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:41:09 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837269.7398] audit: op="connection-delete" uuid="be4449bb-19c4-437e-91fb-5e54f30fe063" name="PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1" pid=1676 uid=1001 result="success"
mar 15 16:41:29 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837293.8535] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior' (ca5f8693-7437-433b-b647-912b8f854359)
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837293.8554] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="ca5f8693-7437-433b-b647-912b8f854359" name="PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior" pid=1160 uid=1001 result="success"
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837293.8572] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837293.8590] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837293.8637] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837293.8653] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior' has security, but secrets are required.
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837293.8655] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837293.8664] sup-iface[0x27c9170,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc start...
mar 15 16:41:33 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837293.9149] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
mar 15 16:41:34 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <warn>  [1615837294.3059] device (wlp2s0): No agents were available for this request.
mar 15 16:41:36 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:41:36 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:41:37 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:41:40 escolacj25-EC10IS2 kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (3977 > 3972), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50250
mar 15 16:42:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837324.2260] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:42:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837324.2282] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
mar 15 16:42:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <warn>  [1615837324.2313] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior'
mar 15 16:42:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837324.2369] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:42:04 escolacj25-EC10IS2 wpa_supplicant[722]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
mar 15 16:42:23 escolacj25-EC10IS2 dbus-daemon[574]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.40' (uid=1001 pid=1160 comm="nm-applet " label="unconfined")
mar 15 16:42:23 escolacj25-EC10IS2 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
mar 15 16:42:23 escolacj25-EC10IS2 dbus-daemon[574]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
mar 15 16:42:23 escolacj25-EC10IS2 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
mar 15 16:42:35 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:42:40 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:42:40 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:42:41 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:42:44 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.5620] keyfile: add connection in-memory (50722fef-1ca0-4b5f-ba24-8b31f5466692,"PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1")
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.5715] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1' (50722fef-1ca0-4b5f-ba24-8b31f5466692)
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6419] settings-connection[0x2791cf8,50722fef-1ca0-4b5f-ba24-8b31f5466692]: write: successfully commited (keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1 (50722fef-1ca0-4b5f-ba24-8b31f5466692,"PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1") and persist connection)
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6425] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="50722fef-1ca0-4b5f-ba24-8b31f5466692" name="PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1" pid=1160 uid=1001 result="success"
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6494] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6512] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6582] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6607] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1' has security, but secrets are required.
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6609] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6620] sup-iface[0x27c9170,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc start...
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6859] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6891] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6904] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6907] Config: added 'ssid' value 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior'
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6908] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6909] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6911] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6912] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
mar 15 16:43:10 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837390.6913] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 wpa_supplicant[722]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with cc:32:e5:97:cb:c4 (SSID='PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior' freq=2462 MHz)
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 kernel: wlp2s0: authenticate with cc:32:e5:97:cb:c4
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 kernel: wlp2s0: send auth to cc:32:e5:97:cb:c4 (try 1/3)
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 kernel: wlp2s0: authenticated
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 wpa_supplicant[722]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with cc:32:e5:97:cb:c4 (SSID='PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior' freq=2462 MHz)
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837392.2522] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 kernel: wlp2s0: associate with cc:32:e5:97:cb:c4 (try 1/3)
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 kernel: wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from cc:32:e5:97:cb:c4 (capab=0x31 status=0 aid=1)
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 kernel: wlp2s0: associated
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 wpa_supplicant[722]: wlp2s0: Associated with cc:32:e5:97:cb:c4
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 wpa_supplicant[722]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837392.2773] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837392.2788] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 wpa_supplicant[722]: wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with cc:32:e5:97:cb:c4 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 wpa_supplicant[722]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to cc:32:e5:97:cb:c4 completed [id=0 id_str=]
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 wpa_supplicant[722]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837392.3191] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837392.3193] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior'.
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837392.3198] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837392.3492] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837392.3570] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): dhclient started with pid 1810
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 avahi-daemon[564]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::fb3d:a98a:602b:40ca.
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 avahi-daemon[564]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 avahi-daemon[564]: Registering new address record for fe80::fb3d:a98a:602b:40ca on wlp2s0.*.
mar 15 16:43:12 escolacj25-EC10IS2 dhclient[1810]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x71e96137)
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 dhclient[1810]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.107 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3761e971)
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 dhclient[1810]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.107 from 192.168.0.1
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 dhclient[1810]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.107 from 192.168.0.1
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5224] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   address 192.168.0.107
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5226] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5227] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   gateway 192.168.0.1
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5229] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   lease time 7200
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5230] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '192.168.0.1'
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5231] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 avahi-daemon[564]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.107.
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 avahi-daemon[564]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 avahi-daemon[564]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.107 on wlp2s0.IPv4.
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5370] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5415] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5436] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.5449] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 dhclient[1810]: bound to 192.168.0.107 -- renewal in 2768 seconds.
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.7813] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.7820] policy: set 'PROFESSORES_CaldasJunior 1' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837393.7845] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 dbus-daemon[574]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=0 pid=721 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 dbus-daemon[574]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 nm-dispatcher[1822]: req:1 'up' [wlp2s0]: new request (2 scripts)
mar 15 16:43:13 escolacj25-EC10IS2 nm-dispatcher[1822]: req:1 'up' [wlp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
mar 15 16:43:14 escolacj25-EC10IS2 systemd-resolved[458]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
mar 15 16:43:14 escolacj25-EC10IS2 systemd-resolved[458]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
mar 15 16:43:15 escolacj25-EC10IS2 NetworkManager[721]: <info>  [1615837395.1577] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
mar 15 16:43:15 escolacj25-EC10IS2 nm-dispatcher[1822]: req:2 'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
mar 15 16:43:15 escolacj25-EC10IS2 nm-dispatcher[1822]: req:2 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
mar 15 16:43:16 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: Listen normally on 4 wlp2s0 192.168.0.107:123
mar 15 16:43:16 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: Listen normally on 5 wlp2s0 [fe80::fb3d:a98a:602b:40ca%3]:123
mar 15 16:43:16 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpd[803]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
mar 15 16:43:16 escolacj25-EC10IS2 ntpdate[1867]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting
```

**IMPORTANT: I found out on 17/03/21 something that must be related. When I reinstall gnome-keyring (which I had removed from all because it pop up window and I don't wan't anything storing/managing passwords or showing up/bothering during the use of the computer) the problem goes away for the user aluno/student.**

Comment: Have you looked in /var/log/messages (or thereabouts) to see if you can see any relevant  error messages ?

Comment: @Lqueryvg I don't see any relevante message there (of course there are plenty but I don't exactly what to focus at). I look into syslog, faillog, auth.log but none seem to have details on the problem I experiencing.

Comment: Please add more info about what happens when a non-admin user logs in? I am confused as to why the network would get disconnected after the admin user logs out... so perhaps you can elaborate on that (or am I just confused here? I run 100s of mint machines and never have seen it disconnect after setting up a network after the admin user logs out).

Comment: @number9 When I try to connect any network with this new user (aluno/student) it simply does not ask the key, and show that you are disconected. Not even networks already set for the admin acc work here. I only get internet for this specific user if I use cable (ethernet) or if I make the trick of setting network via hidden option (that is say I enter the option for setting hidden network, I type the SSID [which is actually not hidden, SIC], choose the WPA2 security and Type the Key)

Comment: You could also try looking in journalctl output. Or even run journalctl -f in a window while you reproduce the problem. See if it shows anything relevant ?

Comment: It seems to me that you are facing the same problem as described here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=188155
Referenced also from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247079/linux-mint-does-not-ask-for-wifi-username-and-password-eduroam-at-university
And, looking at this particular answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492026/66357 it makes me wonder if you need to do something special to connect to the school's network, for example use a specific installer or install a certificate ?

Comment: Does this happen for *all* wifi networks ? Do you have a portable wifi hotspot (e.g. phone with data tethering) you could try to connect to ?

Comment: As far as I know the problem occur with all wifi listed, but I still have to test unsecured ones and those via tethering. Diring this week I will proceed the tests suggested like trying other networks and run journalctl during the attempts to connect... And regarding the threads above, yes they all seem to be relating the same issue (or almost the same -  all networks even particlar ones show the same problem. It is not exclusive for the school wifi list).

Comment: I edited the thread in order to add the results of the new tests I performed... Please take a look!! And yes, the problem occur with all wifi network!

Comment: I Just found out something that must be related. When I reinstall gnome-keyring (which I had removed from all because they pop up window asking to mange passwords and I don't wan't anything storing/ managing passwords or showing up during the use of the computer) the problem goes away for the user aluno/student.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not "allowed" to add a comment: @claudia
Log into your system with your account and issue `sudo usermod -aG sudo *username*` in a terminal, where *username* is the user in question.

Sudo privileges are defined in the /etc/sudoers file. Adding the user to this file allows you to grant customized access to the commands and configure individual security policies - just as a hint since you wanted to limit what the users can do on the system.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem... I still cannot connect the wifi networks I intend because the window asking password just doesn't pop up. I edited the thread informing that journalctl result also doesnt show important changes  with sudo privileges...
And having this user to sudo group I add the problem os leting the students to make system changes that they sould not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running LM 19.3 32 bit and after an update a few days ago from

wpa=2:2.6ubuntu2.6 to wpa=2:2.6ubuntu2.8

bluetooth didn't work anymore.

Going Back with timeshift and it is working again !?

Comment: interesting...The only two standart packages I removed from the distribution were timeshift (cause it prompt window  for backups) and gnome-keyring (cause it prompted window asking to set a master password and to manage passwords). I don't like things interrupting during the use of the computer. Aparently we have to find/learn other solutions instead of removing those annoying packagens. I did not tested bluetooth on those machines but now I already know on what suspect if something related will fail :D